# Aggregate function with case statement

Tags: sql, case, aggregate

I am trying to use the aggregate function with a CASE statement but I am not getting the syntax right.
I am attaching the sample code with the question on what I am trying to achieve but I get the syntax error.

```
count(case when weekminus1 = 0 and week0 = 1 then distinct(asin) end) as asin_added,
count(case when weekminus1 = 0 and week0 = 1 then distinct(fnsku) end) as fnsku_added,
```

Any leads will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yo want to express this as:

```
count(distinct case when weekminus1 = 0 and week0 = 1 then asin end) as asin_added,
count(distinct case when weekminus1 = 0 and week0 = 1 thenfnsku end) as fnsku_added,
```